# Checking in a colleague's file who has gone away

Tags: tfs

I have inherited a codebase with a few checked out files from a colleague, who is now away for several weeks. Is there any way I can check in his files?

This is TFS 2012.

Thanks

Comment: Plug his HD into our motherboard, browse through his files. When Windows complains that you don't own his folders, take ownership. Now you can check everything he's got there.

Answer (score 2):

If he has put the changes up as a shelveset you are in luck... it is now very easy. In that situation you just "unshelve" the shelveset then check those changes in as yourself. Make sure you have checked in or suspended any other work you are doing before you unshelve the shelveset or it will merge those changes with your other work.

Comment: This is the method that my company follows when someone takes leave for awhile. Seems like the right way to go.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the TF.exe CHECKIN command. There is an option called "author"

/author:author name

Identifies the author of the pending changes so that one user can check in changes on behalf of another user.Requires the CheckinOther permission

[TF CHECKIN MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c327ca1z.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you can check-in his changes on his behalf, especially if his computer is turned off ;).

What you can do is to undo check-out of the files he has but you’ll need additional privileges for that.

You can do that with command that looks like

```
tf undo /workspace:OtherUserWorkspace;OtherUser  $/Project/ItemName.cs /s:http://yourtfsserver:8080
```

What you can try is to install TFS Power tools that will allow you to do this from GUI

[image]

Once pending chances are shown you can select any file and undo check in.